# IF foreach = 4 element then display other code

Tags: php, foreach

Hello i have problem with display items.

i have this code:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($results as $result){                  

    if(++$counter === 1) {
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." czasoumilacz'/></li>"; 
    } else if (++$counter === 2){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." granie na czekanie'/></li>"; 
    } else if (++$counter === 3){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." halodzwonek'/></li>"; 
    } else if (++$counter === 4){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." muzyka na czekanie'/></li>"; 
    } else if (++$counter === 5){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." halo granie'/></li>"; 
    } else {
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." czasoumilacz'/></li>"; 
    }  

}
```

I try to do something like this:

if foreach will have second element i will display:

```
$outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." granie na czekanie'/></li>";
```

Next if foreach will give 5th element it will show different code :

```
$outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." czasoumilacz'/></li>";
```

So for each other element i want show different values. How do this?? My code show always last one condition..

Comment: Where are you getting `$key` from??

Comment: it works great :) http://prntscr.com/a651ig thank you! :)

Comment: It would also be useful to see what the `$results` array looks like

Comment: foreach ($results as $counter => $result){

Comment: I did, refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a counter by using just the foreach loop like this

```
foreach ($results as $counter => $result){                  

    if($counter === 1) {
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." czasoumilacz'/></li>"; 
    } else if ($counter === 2){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." granie na czekanie'/></li>"; 
    } else if ($counter === 3){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." halodzwonek'/></li>"; 
    } else if ($counter === 4){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." muzyka na czekanie'/></li>"; 
    } else if ($counter === 5){
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." halo granie'/></li>"; 
    } else {
        $outtext .= "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key." czasoumilacz'/></li>"; 
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized version with `switch` operator:

> In a switch statement, the condition is evaluated only once ...

```
foreach ($results as $counter => $result){ 
    $li_part = "<li><img src='".$result."' alt='".$key;                 
    switch ($counter) {
        case 1:
            $outtext .= $li_part ." czasoumilacz'/></li>";
            break; 
        case 2:
            $outtext .= $li_part ." granie na czekanie'/></li>";
            break;
        case 3:
            $outtext .= $li_part ." halodzwonek'/></li>"; 
            break;
        case 4:
            $outtext .= $li_part ." muzyka na czekanie'/></li>";
            break;
        case 5:
            $outtext .= $li_part ." halo granie'/></li>";
            break;
        default:
            $outtext .= $li_part ." czasoumilacz'/></li>"; 
    }  

}
```